# Convertir un string de un array a tipo array en PHP

Tags: php

En resumidas cuentas tengo algo como esto:

```
$variable = "[{"id":1, "nombre":"Juan"},{"id":2, "nombre":"Manuel"}]"
```

Como verán, es un string y quiero pasarlo a un array, el objetivo es que sea algo como:

```
$variable = [
    ['id' => 1, 'nombre'=>'Juan']
    ['id' => 2, 'nombre'=>'Manuel']
]
```

He investigado, pero no consigo la manera que lo haga funcionar.

Comment: seguro que esa sintáxis es correcta? no debería ser comillas dobles afuera y comillas simples para las claves y valores?

Comment: Intenta con json_decode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La cadena que presentas es considerada en realidad un JSON. Por tanto, existe una función propia para convertir  un JSON a array: esa función  es  **[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)**.

Pero haría falta que la variable empiece y termine por comillas simples, y que le pases un segundo parámetro `TRUE` para que cree un array desde `$variable`, que, como hemos dicho, no es más que un json.

Veamos:

```
/*Creamos la variable empezando y terminado con '*/
$variable = '[{"id":1, "nombre":"Juan"},{"id":2, "nombre":"Manuel"}]';

/*Pasamos la variable y TRUE a json_decode*/
$arr=json_decode($variable,TRUE);   

/*Probamos nuestro array*/
print_r($arr);
```

***Salida:***

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nombre] => Juan
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nombre] => Manuel
        )

)
```

También, podemos recorrerlo desde código para presentar sus valores:

```
foreach ($arr as $row){
    echo "id: ".$row["id"]." - nombre: ".$row["nombre"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

***Salida:***

```
id: 1 - nombre: Juan
id: 2 - nombre: Manuel
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo siguiente puedes utilizar la función explode de PHP e indicarle a través de que elemento va a encontrar para hacer la separación

También creo que estas utilizando mal las comillas, pues si para toda la declaración usas comillas dobles entonces los elementos de clave y valor los va a intentar leer como variables lo cual provocará un error; te debería quedar así

```
$variable = "[{'id':1, 'nombre':'Juan'},{'id':2, 'nombre':'Manuel'}]";
$arreglo = explode(',', $variable);
var_dump($arreglo);
```

> Haz uso de var_dump() para que te muestre la lontitud y los tipos de
>   datos que estan contenidos en la variable $arreglo

Comment: Se que el string tiene un error, y el codigo no solventa el problema.