# Convertir String a Array de tipo Clave => Valor

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo un String con aspecto de Json y quiero convertirlo a un array de tipo clave valor, llevo ya un muy buen rato intentandolo pero no logro dar con la solución a lo que requiero, de que manera podría realizar este proceso?

El String:

```
{
"headers:": {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Digest": "SHA-256=R2uaJxvz//7kwe6vNTcZ9KVDfM1N7MCpoXbf9rr3APk=",
"Signature": "keyId=\"TestApp01\",algorithm=\"hmac-sha384\",headers=\"content-type digest\",signature=\"9WJc5wcu4sn1xDK5oyoZrF_V9VRHFIQkElphSYeqTKPiZTS1GzH6f3cTBt6gM1CR\"
},
"body": {
    "commerceCode": "Código del comercio interno de nequi", 
    "code": "Campo code enviado en el pago, normalmente representa el identificador de la subsidiaria. ",
    "value": "Valor del pago",
    "phoneNumber": "Número de celular del pagador", 
    "messageId": "Identificador único de la transacción",
    "transactionId": "Identificador del pago", 
    "region": "Region del pago P001 (Panama) o C001 (Colombia)",
    "receivedAt": "Fecha en formato JSON de cuando se realizo el pago", 
    "paymentStatus": "Estado del pago, SUCCESS (cuando se realiza el pago de forma exitosa) o CANCELED/REFUSED (si el pago fue cancelado o rechazado)"
}
}
```

Como quiero convertirlo:

```
['headers'] =>
     ['Content-Type'] => 'application/json',
     ['Digest'] => 'SHA-256=R2uaJxvz//7kwe6vNTcZ9KVDfM1N7MCpoXbf9rr3APk=',
     ['Signature'] => 'keyId=\"TestApp01\",algorithm=\"hmac-sha384\",headers=\"content-type digest\",signature=\"9WJc5wcu4sn1xDK5oyoZrF_V9VRHFIQkElphSYeqTKPiZTS1GzH6f3cTBt6gM1CR\',
['body'] => 
    ['commerceCode'] => 'Código del comercio interno de nequi', 
    ['code'] => 'Campo code enviado en el pago, normalmente representa el identificador de la subsidiaria'
```

Estaria infinitamente agradecido me lograran ayudar :D

Comment: Creo que aveces hace falta un respiro, efectivamente me funciona el decode para convertirlo en un objeto php, no me percate antes porque al probar en el postman estaba mandando mal el body y por lo tanto lo marcaba como un string, muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Con json_decode puedes convertirlo a un objeto o un array usando como segundo argumento `true` o `false` (false por omision)

Comment: Acá otra respuesta mejor explicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175478/convertir-un-string-de-un-array-a-tipo-array-en-php?rq=1